# Запись данных из переменных в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

P.S. В mySQL не силен, поэтому прошу написать каким должен быть mySQL запрос чтобы выполнить написанное выше.

Но по какой то причине код не работает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Зачем вы так извращаетесь с чтением JSON? Попробуйте json_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$obj = json_decode('{"profit":"14.4","utm_source":"16009"}');
```

Что касается вопроса, если предположить что $utm_source это id в таблице files, то это может выглядеть примерно так

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$mysqli->query('UPDATE files SET install = install + 1, profit = profit + ? WHERE id = ?');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("di", $obj->profit, $obj->utm_source);
$stmt->execute();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: ? это указатель параметра в prepared statement (параметризированный SQL запрос), заменять ничего не надо, bind_param связывает переменные с  SQL запросом после чего выполняет подготовленный SQL запрос.

Comment: Как можно с эмулировать запрос, для теста скрипта?

Comment: Для теста можно в том же php скрипте определить $data с вашим JSON и работать с $data так же, как вы это делаете с данными полученными через $_POST (или что вы используете для получения данных) и все что связанно с получение данных можно закомментировать.

Comment: по какой то причине не работает, хотя в .json файл все данные пишутся нормально, но не в БД. Подключение вроде работает

Comment: Чуть подправил ваш код, сделал по аналогии с [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php) и все заработало! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Теперь нужно сделать так чтобы если profit больше 1.1 то выполнять sql запрос, а если меньше - не выполнять. Где поставить это условие в коде?

Comment: Правильно (кавычки наверно лучше не использовать), в условние if можно обернуть весь код связанный с изменением данных

Comment: Попробовал сделать без кавычек(добавил в вопрос), но код не работает.