# Отправка двух mySQL запросов

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Первый запрос проходит нормально, второй не записывается.

UPD: Есть бд, в ней таблицы users и files. В таблице users есть поля id, downloads, а в таблице files: id, users_id, downloads, profit, install.

Основной вопрос([Запись данных из переменных в БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443605/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%94))

Comment: А что находится в `$obj->utm_medium`? И если подставить это значение в исходный запрос - он обновляет данные? У вас может нет такой записи в базе

Comment: Посмотрите первый вопрос, и поймете что там. Сейчас попробую поменять запросы местами, и проверить будут ли он работать

Comment: В метке [tag:sql] есть ссылка на хорошую статью о том, как задавать вопросы про sql. Рекомендую )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, наверно, лучше давать [прямую ссылку](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576) или хотя бы на [wiki](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: действительно, там же не сразу wiki.

Comment: Попробовал поменять запросы местами, если отправлять только один запрос(не важно первый или второй) то все нормально записывается в бд, если отправлять оба, то вообще ничего не записывается.

Comment: попробуйте воспользоваться, как и посоветовали в ответе, использовать разные переменные. либо попробуйте после первого `execute()` выполнить `close()`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте для каждого запроса создать отдельный экземпляр stmt